# SQL query speed: estimating matches by querying only part of the database

Tags: sql, bigdata, query-optimization

Ten million rows of data in MySQL database. Attempting to increase speed by estimating the number of results rather than providing an exact figure (like some search engines).

Attempted to estimate the number of results by taking every 10th row of data and then simply multiplying the output by 10 like this:

`SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table WHERE counter mod 10 = 0 AND...`

Unfortunately, this does not increase speed at all. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with what you're doing there is that you're (probably) forcing a table scan, so the RDBMS has to run through each row to work out which ones to take. Which could actually be slower than just running your full query.

When working with big tables like this I try to divide and conquer. Start with the smallest amount of data that you need and then add on to it, as opposed to starting with everything and then cutting down.

So I'd start by trimming down the data set to something more manageable and then running your query on that. So ask yourself, is there any way I can filter this quickly using an index (like take the last 30 days, or the last year)

You also need to know your data and how your users are searching through it. for instance if your data is highly seasonal and changes through out the year, and your users are interested in the sales for the last 30 days, there's no point running your query for 7 months ago because the estimate will be wrong.

You could potentially make use of the inbuilt histogram functionality, you can read more about that [here](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/histogram-statistics-in-mysql/).

You could try seeing if using a LIMIT and ORDER BY RAND() can help to speed things up. Again, this depends on the data, because of the randomness of the results. You might get 1000 results from the best time in your history and return really high estimates, or the worst time in your history and return really low estimates. You'd need to test how the random set compares:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: LIMIT would certainly increase speed, but the problem there is that I would not know how much data had been sampled. Is there someway that I could find out? So in psuedocode, "give me the first 1000 results, tell me how many rows you scanned and then the number of results". I would need four numbers to get an estimate.  results_number * 10,000,000 * (1000 / scanned_rows) = estimate

Comment: In other words, "give me 1000 results, but also tell me how many rows you looked at in order to get that"

Comment: It would take a random 1000 rows from the whole table. So whatever your COUNT(1) is from that table. You could look that up from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES table  too so you don't have to query the table. SELECT TABLE_ROWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table';

Comment: Surely the output would always be 1000. If the search term appears in 10% of the rows or 90%.

Comment: Oh, I see, you need to apply some search criteria and then take an estimate. Not possible I'm afraid without scanning all of the records in the table. Another couple of options: 1: Partition the table and search one of the partitions only without your modulo, 2: Add the modulo column to your table and add an index to it.